# Comparing initial symptoms to a diagnosis

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, p-value, naive-bayes

I have a small dataset of 80 patients with a diagnosis of 3 types of cancer: AML, ALL, and CML. They each come to the hospital with one or two symptoms: Fever, Diarrhea, or both. They all eventually are diagnosed with an infection c. diff.

Is there a way to compare the presenting symptoms (fever or diarrhea) to possibly show a statistically significant difference in the performance of the symptom as a way of predicting ultimate infection?

The dataset does not include patients who tested negative for the infection ie. fever or diarrhea without infection. I was considering naive bayes or chi squared, but I'm not sure its possible without the negative results.

Comment: If you want to know how frequently the symptoms occur when there is no diagnosis of cancer you have no information to determine it.

Comment: right, thats what I was thinking. I'm not trying to see how frequently they occur, just whether in the case of an existing cancer diagnosis, fever or diarrhea is a better predictor of this specific infection

Comment: Then you just compare how the proportion of times each predictor gets it right. The only problem is whether or not your tests will have much power given the small sample size.

Comment: hm, but there aren't any times in this set that it would be counted as wrong ie. fever w/o infection, or diarrhea w/o infection. its, 80 patients with infection, 30 presented with a fever and 40 presented with diarrhea, and 10 presented with both. I can't get a statistic suggesting significance based on that alone right?

Comment: I was thinking incorrectly that the symptoms could lead to diagnosis AML when the diagnosis was actually ALL. But all that is indicated is that one of the three types of cancer occurred. So you are correct that you have no way to compare the accuracy of the symptoms without failed cases.